# Why does std::distance doesn't work on iterator of unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, int> umap;
    unordered_map<int, int>::iterator itr1, itr2;
    itr1 = umap.begin();
    itr2 = std::next(itr1, 3);
    cout << distance(itr2, itr1);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine. But produces a `Segmentation fault` upon executing.

Why can't I find the distance between iterators?

Comment: Maybe because a *distance* implicitly implies an *order*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.

1. `umap` is empty, then `std::next(itr1, 3)` returns an invalid iterator.
2. Change the order of the arguments passed to [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

> InputIt must meet the requirements of LegacyInputIterator. The operation is more efficient if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator
>
> If InputIt is not LegacyRandomAccessIterator, the behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first. If InputIt is LegacyRandomAccessIterator, the behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first and first is not reachable from last.

E.g.

```
unordered_map<int, int> umap { {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3} };
unordered_map<int, int>::iterator itr1, itr2;
itr1 = umap.begin();
itr2 = std::next(itr1, 3);
cout << distance(itr1, itr2);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HuBAi2GsbJuIxFeG)

Answer (score 2):

Result of `std::next(itr1, 3)` is beyond `umap.end()` and is the source of segfault. More of,  `umap.end()` and  `umap.begin()` would be invalidated by content of `unordered_map`. This would work but wouldn't allow use of `std::distance` anyway:

```
umap[0] = 3;
umap[1] = 4;
umap[2] = 5;
umap[3] = 5;
itr1 = umap.begin();
itr2 = std::next(itr1, 3);
```

`unordered_map` in an unordered container, doesn't have RandomAccessIterator and `std::distance` can't be used on its iterators.

Comment: *Result of std::next(itr1, 3) is beyond umap.end()* ahh I missed that.

Comment: Would you mind If I edit my answer into your answer? Since your answer is more complete than mine.

Comment: @Ch3steR you found links for those terms faster. ^,^

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance: `If InputIt is not LegacyRandomAccessIterator, the behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first`. So behavior is undefined only `if last is not reachable from first`. so std::distance can be used for `itr1` and `itr2` only in this order and it takes O(distance) operations

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Swift-FridayPie. The documentation says `last` should be reachable from `first` by increment operations, which wasn't the case with my code. I fixed it (after populating the unordered_map) & the segfault is resolved. So, it does look like `std::distance` can be used on unordered_map's iterators